# Can't resolve 'Type argument is not within bounds of type-variable' error

Tags: java, generics

I have a generic class `ShortestPathVertex` which implements `Comparable`:

```
public class ShortestPathVertex<E extends Number> implements VertexInterface, Comparable<ShortestPathVertex<E>>
```

And another generic Class `MinPriorityQueue` that requires a `Comparable` type parameter:

```
public class MinPriorityQueue<T extends Comparable<T>>
```

And I need to create a `MinPriorityQueue` instance with `ShortestPathVertex` as the type parameter:

```
public static <E extends Number, T extends ShortestPathVertex<E>> void Dijkstra(WeightedDirectedGraph<T, E> G, int s) {
        MinPriorityQueue<T> Q = new MinPriorityQueue<>(G.getVertices(), G.V()); // error
}
```

When I compile it throws error:

```
ShortestPath.java:60: error: type argument T#1 is not within bounds of type-variable T#2
        MinPriorityQueue<T> Q = new MinPriorityQueue<>(G.getVertices(), G.V());
                         ^
  where T#1,E,T#2 are type-variables:
    T#1 extends ShortestPathVertex<E> declared in method <E,T#1>Dijkstra(WeightedDirectedGraph<T#1,E>,int)
    E extends Number declared in method <E,T#1>Dijkstra(WeightedDirectedGraph<T#1,E>,int)
    T#2 extends Comparable<T#2> declared in class MinPriorityQueue
ShortestPath.java:60: error: cannot infer type arguments for MinPriorityQueue<>
        MinPriorityQueue<T> Q = new MinPriorityQueue<>(G.getVertices(), G.V());
                                ^
2 errors
```

Considering that `ShortestPathVertex` implements `Comparable` i don't understand what is it complaining about. Why is it saying that `ShortestPathVertex` is not withing bounds of `Comparable` and how do I fix it. I'm using Java 7.0.

Comment: Have you tried a newer Java compiler? Java 7 is definitively obsolete at this point.

Comment: I can't find the error here, so unless this is a problem with an older compiler (Java before 9 was known to have some rather dumb pitfalls in generic inference), I'm stumped.

Comment: @chrylis I'm using an old laptop with version 7 of java installed on it, didn't try newer versions. I'd rather have a code that works with all versions of java though.

Comment: So what happens if you use a type witness at the place you call `Dijkstra`? (Note, by the way, that you're not following Java code conventions regarding naming of variables and members.)

Comment: @chrylis Sorry I don't know what 'type witness' is, i'm not that advanced in generics. (I should be following the code formatting guidelines, but this code is only practice of the algorithms in CLRS book and I'm trying to keep the namings similar to the pseudo code :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line

```
public class MinPriorityQueue<T extends Comparable<T>>
```

to this:

```
public class MinPriorityQueue<T extends Comparable<? super T>>
```

The issue here is that `T extends ShortestPathVertex<E>` in method `Dijkstra`, so `T` needs not implement `Comparable` directly. But this was necessary in your version of `MinPriorityQueue`. My change fixes this problem.

Explanation: `In MinPriorityQueue<T> Q = ...` `T` is a subtype of `ShortestPathVertex<E>` which implements `Comparable<ShortestPathVertex<E>>`. This means `T` is comparable to values of type `ShortestPathVertex<E>` (which is a super type of `T`). But in your version of `MinPriorityQueue` you define that `T` must be comparable to the same type `T`. If you also want to accept super type, you must define it by `<? super T>`.

You can try (just for demonstration): In method `Dijkstra` substitute every occurence of `T` by `ShortestPathVertex<E>`. This works also with the simpler definition of class `MinPriorityQueue`.

Another example for using `super` in this way: Look at the method `Collections.binarySearch` in the Java Class Library.

Comment: Thanks your solution worked perfectly. Could you just please elaborate more on `so T needs not implement Comparable directly`? I don't understand how would `ShortestPathVertex` not implement `Comparable` when it's already declared to do that.